# Schematic editor capable of diagonal components

Tags: schematics, software

I've found several great editors capable of vertical and horizontal components, but none that can do diagonal ones. Are there any available?

**Edit** - This is purely cosmetic. I've just started an introduction to circuits course and a  good deal of the exercises involve diagonal components. AFAIK, in all cases these can be redrawn to vertical-horizontal schematics, but I'd like to show the original circuit as well.

Comment: Yes.  I know of at least one, although probably most of them can do it.

Comment: Do you mean positioning of parts in a schematic, or footprints in a PCB layout? For the former, I am not sure I see the importance, other than perhaps cosmetic nicety. Could you please help me understand why it matters? For footprints on a PCB layout, pretty much every product I have seen permits at least 45 degree increments, if not arbitrary-angle positioning.

Comment: @Anindo The former. I've updated the question with details.

Comment: For a matrix a diagonal part such as a diode, LED, switch or resistor might make the schematic considerably more clear. Andy's solution is the best, most likely, because turning a part at 45 degrees would take the hot spot connection points off the internal grid. A custom part would keep the hotspots on-grid.

Comment: @OlinLathrop Care to share? I've looked into about 8 right now, ranging from demos of software to online ones. Mostly the results found from "schematic editor" and similar searches. None of the ones could do out-of-the-box angled components, at least not obviously.

Comment: Hmm, I just checked on KiCAD and Proteus, both have some basic schematic symbols (just passives, apparently) available as 45-degree aligned alternatives. Interesting that I never needed to use those, but now I might :-)

Comment: @Mirov You might want to either follow Andy's approach, or download the angled symbols from some user-contributed source, depending on the particular schematic editor you prefer.

Comment: @Anindo Looks like I'll be doing just that. In a perfect world, components could be rotated to arbitrary angles, but I suppose that wouldn't have much practical use. Thanks!

Comment: The Pulsonix software I use lets me rotate parts (schematic and PCB) by any angle. I've only ever used 90 and 45 degrees.

Comment: Pretty sure Altium allows setting rotation angle to 45 and 90 degrees, thus allowing your diagonal symbols

Comment: @KyranF I don't think you can rotate schematic symbols to other than 90° increments in Altium (or Orcad), nor can you directly rotate the schematic primitives in the symbol editor by other than increments of 90°. Of course **footprints** can be rotated to any arbitrary angle. I can only imagine how ugly schematics could be with components at random angles and ransom-note fonts used everywhere.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany hmm.. yes it seems you are right. I must have mistaken footprint rotation steps using spacebar with similar functionality in schematic editor. I guess for the rare few components the OP needs with diagonal symbols can just make custom symbols. Only takes a few minutes hehe

Comment: In general it is customary for all components in a schematic to either be horizontal or vertical. Otherwise it gets very sloppy and confusing. I recommend simply sticking with only vertical or horizontal schematic elements.

Answer (score 6):

The direct answer to your question is "Yes".

However, you should ask yourself why you really want diagonal components in a schematic.  You say it's for cosmetic reasons, but that's exactly why you DON'T want diagonal components most of the time.  There is a good reason most components are defined oriented either horizontally or vertically.  Other than for a small number of exceptions, diagonal components make a schemtatic harder and more annoying to read.

You may not care yet if you're new to reading schematics, but after a while, properly drawn subsystems will look similar accross many schematics.  This allows them to pop out at you, sortof like how you read the words of sentences as whole entities and don't decipher them from the individual letters most of the time.  If you break these patterns, other will find your schematics annoying to read.

The two most common places I see diagonal components is a diode full-wave bridge or something like a wheatstone bridge.  A wheatstone bridge is hardly used anymore, but in any case, both can be drawn just as well by using vertically oriented parts.  Here is a diode full wave bridge, for example:

[image]

In this one case, a diamond arrangement for the diodes would have been acceptable, but this vertical version is just as readable and nobody will object to it.

In fact, I'd say that when you're starting out with schematics, don't use diagonal components.  Consider then outright wrong.  Eventually you will learn in what rare cases they are acceptable, and then you can use them if you really think it adds clarity.  However, for now it is good to learn to draw schematics with only vertical and horizontal components, even if someone gives you schematics with diagonal components.

Comment: +1, I strongly agree with you on this... After reading the question, I have given careful thought to what schematic I would actually consider "better" with diagonal components. The only application that seemed to make sense was a diode matrix for a scanned keypad, e.g. a 5x5 keypad. Even there, using orthogonal diodes instead of diagonal looks a bit better to me, but this seems to be a popular use of diagonal symbols out there on the web.

Comment: @Anindo: Good point about the diode matrix, I didn't think of that one. I've seen that too and I think it's acceptable. But, as you say, it can be drawn just as well with vertical or horizontal diodes too. It's hard to come up with a legitimate need for diagonal components.  I just got a downvote, so apparently someone disagrees.  It would be nice to know what exactly they had in mind.

Comment: Someone emotionally attached to diagonals, perhaps?

Comment: I agree with you entirely. The limited schematics that I've seen have all been horizontal-vertical. That said, the class textbook has featured a number of diagonal examples, the most memorable being a wheatstone bridge. I just want to be able to record them on my notes.

Answer (score 5):

Every decent schematic editor I've used has a built-in library shape editor. If you need a diagonal component such as a resistor at 45 degrees then create one as a part and save it to your library.

Answer (score 0):

Eagle allows you to rotate objects by 45 degrees using the ROTATE command (but not via the mouse alone).

Comment: Or you can use the toolbar to rotate by 38 degrees if you want.